# how to store a list of array items in to one array

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Here's a subroutine which reads a text file that includes an employee's details.
I've stored for each line from the file to temporary array and I wanted to make it so that per 5 lines/5 array items, it stores them into one array. How do I make it so that storing array of size eg. 0-4 (5 items) into an array of type string?

Example:

1. temparray[0] = John Frank
2. temparray[1] = ID204
3. temparray[2] = Permanent worker
4. temparray[3] = Manager
5. temparray[4] = 0 (additional payments)

into one array that stores all these 5 lists, so maybe like:

for x = 0 to 4 step 1

store_array(1) = temparray(x)

next x

but after doing this, I used console.writeline to show store_array(1) and it only displays 0.

```
    Dim arremp() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)     'adds each line as string array
    Dim temp As String = " "
    Dim flen As Integer = arremp.Length - 1 'get string length, index based, starting at 0 not 1.
    Dim temparray(flen) As String   'string array
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    '   Setting up an object variable for the streamreader (which is the path folder and its name).
    Dim objreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filename, True) ' Has been set to true because the file exists and this will append(ADD) for the next str.
    '   if a file doesn't exists, it should be false which will ensure that a text file is created first.

    For Each myline In arremp
        temp = myline & vbCrLf
        temparray(i) = temp
        i = i + 1
    Next myline
```

Comment: It's VB.NET code - not VBA.

Comment: @QHarr My bad, this is in VB.NET code and JohnyL stated it already. I've added example underneath my question.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused but you might want to look at ArrayLists under System.Collections https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: alright cheers @QHarr

Comment: There are such things as multidimensional arrays. In your case 2-dimensional. But I think the Davids idea of a class (or structure) is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off creating an Employee class - For example :-

```
Private Class Employee
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property ID As String
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property JobTitle As String
    Public Property AdditionalPayments As Integer
End Class
```

Then instead of using arrays, create a list of employees like this

```
Dim employees As New List(Of Employee)
```

To read the data you can write it still using io.file, but to be honest I would recommend having a look as streamreaders and the keyword `Using`

```
Private Sub EmployeeData()
    'this is a more readable way of creating a nonexistant file or
    'reading from an existing one
    If Not IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
        'if the file exists create it
        IO.File.Create(filename)
        tempfile.Close()
    Else
        'otherwise read the data from the existing file
        Dim arremp() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)     'adds each line as string array
        'you dont need i to track the number of items in the list of employees, just use employees.Count

        'Loop through the array 5 items at a time, create a tempEmployee
        'and add it to the list of employees
        For x As Integer = 0 To arremp.Count - 1 Step 5
            Dim tempEmployee As New Employee With {.Name = arremp(x),
                                                   .ID = arremp(x + 1),
                                                   .Type = arremp(x + 2),
                                                   .JobTitle = arremp(x + 3),
                                                   .AdditionalPayments = arremp(x + 4)
                                                   }
            employees.Add(tempEmployee)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Now instead of referring to an employee using an array, which in 6 months time you won't remember which element means what, you can just use more obvious property names like so ..

```
TextBox1.Text = employees(i).Name
TextBox1.Text = employees(i).JobTitle
```